# How do I get this small empty box?

Tags: box

I'm trying to copy over a question from my math homework to LaTeX, and can't figure out how to replicate this box between `$G_1$` and `$G_2$`:

[image]

I've tried `\qed`, but that is always preceded with a space:
[image]

I've tried `\fbox{}`, but it is too low in the line: [image]

How do you think my professor achieved the box?

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! `\qed`is for the end of proofs. Did you try `\Box`  or the `ams` `\square`?

Comment: thanks for the welcome. also wow, I should have known it would be as easy as `\square` Thanks! Leave that as an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: That's not really necessary. B. t.w., to have a proper spacing, you probably should use it as `\mathbin{\square}` (or define a personal macro as a shortcut).

Comment: ok, thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out `$\square$` did the job. D'oh. `$\Box$` also works.